# Symfony Datatables button pages don't work

Tags: symfony, datatables

I'm using DataTables but I don't understand why in table my symfony page don't work when i press page 2,3 etc..

my html code is

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

    <div class="container">
        {{ form_start(form,{'attr':{'novalidate':'novalidate'}}) }}
        <div class="row" >
            <div class=" col-md-4 form-group">
                {{ form_row(form.data_inizio,{'attr':{'class':'form-control'}}) }}
            </div>
            <div class=" col-md-4 form-group">
                {{ form_row(form.data_fine,{'attr':{'class':'form-control'}}) }}
            </div>  
            <div class="col-md-4  form-group">
                {{ form_row(form.Stampa,{'attr':{'class':'form-control'}}) }}
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>

    {{ form_end(form) }}

    {#</div>#}


    <div class=row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1>Elenco Analisi</h1>  
        </div>  
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {# <p style="text-align:right;width:100%;">
             <span style="font-weight:bold;">Totale:</span> <input type="text" id="totale" name="totale" maxlength="50" disabled/>&nbsp; 

         </p>#}
        </div>
    </div>
    <table id="tblSearch" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Codice</th>
                <th>Effettuato da</th>
                <th>Data</th>
                <th>Proprietario</th>
                <th>Autorizzata da </th>
                <th>Laboratorio</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Stampa</t>
                <th>Accettazione</th>
                <th>Totale</th>
                <th>Totale Scontato</th>
                <th>File</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Codice</th>
                <th>Effettuato da</th>
                <th>Data</th>
                <th>Proprietario</th>
                <th>Autorizzata da </th>
                <th>Laboratorio</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Stampa</th>
                <th>Accettazione</th>
                <th>Totale</th>
                <th>Totale Scontato</th>
                <th>File</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>


        <tbody>
            {% for singola_analisi in analisi %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{singola_analisi.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{singola_analisi.codice}}</td>
                    <td>{{singola_analisi.idUser.nome}}</td>
                    <td>{{ singola_analisi.data|date('d-m-Y') }}</td>
                    <td>{{singola_analisi.idProprietario.ragionesociale}} </td>
                    <td>{{singola_analisi.autoriazzatada.nome}} {{singola_analisi.autoriazzatada.cognome}}</td>
                    <td>{{singola_analisi.idLaboratorio.nome}}</td>
                    {#  <td><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></td>#}


                    {#                    #}
                    {% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}  
                        {#                        se è sua l'analisi#}
                        {% if user.id==singola_analisi.iduser.id %}  
                           {% if singola_analisi.stato == 1 %}
                              <td><a href="{{ path('edit_analisi', { 'id_analisi': singola_analisi.id }) }}"><i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
                               <td><a href="{{ path('stampa', { 'id_analisi': singola_analisi.id }) }}"><i class="fa fa-file" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
                               <td>
                                    <a href="{{ path('accettazione', { 'id_analisi': singola_analisi.id,'codice':singola_analisi.conferma}) }}"><button type="button">Accetta</button></a>

                                    <a href="{{ path('rifiuto', { 'id_analisi': singola_analisi.id,'codice':singola_analisi.conferma }) }}"><button style="margin-top:2px;" type="button">Rifiuta  </button></a>
                                </td>
                            {% elseif singola_analisi.stato == 2%}
                                <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>     
                                <td><a href="{{ path('stampa', { 'id_analisi': singola_analisi.id }) }}"><i class="fa fa-file" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>

                                <td>
                                    <a href="{{ path('accettazione', { 'id_analisi': singola_analisi.id,'codice':singola_analisi.conferma}) }}"><button type="button">Accetta</button></a>

                                    <a href="{{ path('rifiuto', { 'id_analisi': singola_analisi.id,'codice':singola_analisi.conferma }) }}"><button style="margin-top:2px;" type="button">Rifiuta  </button></a>
                                </td>
                            {% else %}
                                <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>     
                                <td><a href="{{ path('stampa', { 'id_analisi': singola_analisi.id }) }}"><i class="fa fa-file" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
                                <td>Accettata</td>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% else %}
                            {% if singola_analisi.stato == 1 %}
                                <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                                <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                                <td>In Elaborazione</td>
                            {% elseif singola_analisi.stato == 2%}
                                <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>     
                                <td><a href="{{ path('stampa', { 'id_analisi': singola_analisi.id }) }}"><i class="fa fa-file" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="{{ path('accettazione', { 'id_analisi': singola_analisi.id,'codice':singola_analisi.conferma}) }}"><button type="button">Accetta</button></a>

                                    <a href="{{ path('rifiuto', { 'id_analisi': singola_analisi.id,'codice':singola_analisi.conferma }) }}"><button style="margin-top:2px;" type="button">Rifiuta  </button></a>
                                </td>
                            {% else %}
                                <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>     
                                <td><a href="{{ path('stampa', { 'id_analisi': singola_analisi.id }) }}"><i class="fa fa-file" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
                                <td>Accettata</td>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endif %} 
                    {% else %}
                        {% if singola_analisi.stato == 1 %}
                            <td><a href="{{ path('edit_analisi', { 'id_analisi': singola_analisi.id }) }}"><i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
                            <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                            <td><a href="{{ path('richiediaccettazione', { 'id_analisi': singola_analisi.id }) }}"><button type="button">Richiedi accettazione</button></a></td>
                        {% elseif singola_analisi.stato == 2%}
                            <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>     
                            <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                            <td>Accettazione in attesa</td>
                        {% else %}

                            <td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>     
                            <td><a href="{{ path('stampa', { 'id_analisi': singola_analisi.id }) }}"><i class="fa fa-file" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
                            <td>Accettato</td>
                        {% endif %} 

                    {% endif %}

                    <td>{{singola_analisi.totale}}</td>
                    <td>{{singola_analisi.totalescontato}}</td>
                    <td>
                        {% if singola_analisi.path != NULL %}
                            <a href="{{ asset('uploads/analisi/' ~ singola_analisi.path ) }}"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            {% else %}
                            <a href="{{path('uploadfile', { 'idanalisi': singola_analisi.id })}}"><i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            {% endif %}
                    </td>
                </tr>


            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table> 

{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }} 
    <script src="{{ asset('js/lista_modulo.js') }}"></script>


{% endblock %}
```

My js code is:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

        $('#tblSearch').DataTable( {
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [ 0 ],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false,

            },

        ],
        "order": [[0, 'desc']],
    } );
});
```

and in my base.html file there is:

```
 {% block stylesheets %}
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
{#        <link href="{{ asset('css/jqueryautocomplete/autocomplete.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">#}
         <link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap-chosen/bootstrap-chosen.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <link href="{{ asset('css/template_base.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css')}}">
          <link href="{{asset('js/plugins/data-tables/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css')}}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection">  
        {% endblock %}

 {% block javascripts %}
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/jqueryautocomplete/chosen.jquery.js')}}"</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/plugins/data-tables/data-tables-script.js')}}"></script>    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/plugins/data-tables/js/jquery.dataTables.js')}}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/plugins/data-tables/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js')}}"></script>
    {% endblock %}
```

i try to load also a example from tutorial but still page button don't work .
I see some forum but noting help me to undestard my problem .

Please can help me to understand?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have error in console ? And your question is not related with Symfony but with JavaScript

Comment: no error in console.i'm using symfony and  i don't know if in some code there is javascript that go in conflict with Datatables